# How to get correct latitude and longitude while I am indoor on a Windows Phone?

Tags: gps, windows-phone

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude information from a Windows Phone through the [GeoCoordinate Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.aspx). When I'm outdoor or under the sky directly, I'm able to get the values instantly but when I'm indoor or inside a room, I'm getting completely wrong values. Is there a way to get my exact location when I am indoor?

N.B. Even when switching my Wi-Fi on, I am getting wrong coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on the GPS hardware primarily and secondly on the Service provider's ability to track your device based on towers. So I doubt if you can do anything. To confirm this you can check the default Maps application. If that works then there is some problem in your application. I had seen similar problems on bada OS devices but it was a GPS hardware problem.